# Unique multidimensional arrays values with different key values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a MySQL table where I store all the website page loads in something like this:
[IP] [date] [hostname]

The main query is something like

```
$log = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM log");
```

Then I put all the values into an array:

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($log)) {
  $log_array[] = $result;
}
```

So now I have a PHP array named $log_array with aprox. 20K rows.
Obviously there are duplicate IP entries.
Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 12.34.56.78
            [date] => 2014-11-25 22:03:01
            [host] => fakehost1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 12.34.56.78
            [date] => 2014-11-25 22:03:01
            [host] => fakehost1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 98.76.54.32
            [date] => 2014-11-25 22:03:03
            [host] => fakehost2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 12.34.56.78
            [date] => 2014-11-25 22:03:05
            [host] => fakehost3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 98.76.54.32
            [date] => 2014-11-25 22:03:06
            [host] => fakehost2
        )
)
```

I would like to obtain an array with unique IP addresses and the last date and last host, and also count the duplicate IPs, so I would like to obtain something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 12.34.56.78
            [times] => 3
            [lastdate] => 2014-11-25 22:03:05
            [lasthost] => fakehost3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 98.76.54.32
            [times] => 2
            [lastdate] => 2014-11-25 22:03:06
            [lasthost] => fakehost2
        )
)
```

I've been trying to solve this for weeks reading everywhere and learning the php array functions but I can't see how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you also have record ids in the table? Or only those 3 fields?

Comment: I also have an 'id' field with auto-increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using PHP

You'd use a `foreach`. For example: https://eval.in/227238

```
$arrFinal = array();
foreach($a as $record) {
   if( array_key_exists($record['ip'], $arrFinal) ) {
     //Update
     $arrFinal[$record['ip']]['times'] += 1; //+1 to the time
     if( strtotime($record['date']) > strtotime($arrFinal[$record['ip']]['lastdate']) ) {
         //This is a newer record
         $arrFinal[$record['ip']]['lastdate'] = $record['date']; //Update last date
         $arrFinal[$record['ip']]['lasthost'] = $record['host']; //Update last host
     }
   } else {
      //New entry
      $arrFinal[$record['ip']] = array(
        'ip' => $record['ip'],
        'times' => 1,
        'lastdate' => $record['date'],
        'lasthost' => $record['host']
      );
   }
}
```

#### Using MySQL

```
select l1.ip,
       count(l1.`ip`) as times,
       max(l1.`date`) as lasttime,
       (select l2.`host` as lasthost 
        from log l2
        where l2.ip = l1.ip
        order by `date` desc 
        limit 1) as lasthost
from log l1
group by l1.`ip`
```

With the same [dummy results in the PHP example](https://eval.in/227238) we'd get the following result set;

```
+-----------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| ip        | times | lasttime            | lasthost  |
+-----------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| 127.0.0.1 |     3 | 2014-11-25 22:03:01 | localhost |
| 88.88.88  |     2 | 2014-11-25 22:03:01 | google    |
+-----------+-------+---------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set
```

Comment: OP said they have `aprox. 20K rows`. This php solution requires bringing back all those rows from mysql to PHP and looping over them. And the mysql result is showing 2014-11-23 as lastdate for localhost whereas your fiddle has 11-25 as well. That is the last date for localhost

Comment: Changes made to the query :) I offered the PHP answer as well because PHP was tagged

Comment: The query seems to work but it takes 24 seconds to process. Too slow.

Comment: I did now. It works like a charm. 0.1s. This is correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries. Example:

```
SELECT l.ip, COUNT(SELECT * FROM log l2 WHERE l.ip = l2.ip) as times FROM log GROUP BY ip
```

Obviously, you need to extend it by your other values.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
$log = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ip,date,host,count(*) as tot FROM log GROUP by ip ");
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I didn't knew that "GROUP BY" could do this. But, in the results y don't get the last host or the last date. The query should select the last item from each group. Good thing is this query only takes 0.07 seconds to process.
I'll post the solution if I find it.

Comment: on the group statement add `ORDER BY` and use `ORDER BY ip,date,host GROUP by ip,date,host` if you want the last item for

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) statement.

```
$log = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT ip, times, lastdate, lasthost FROM log");
```